# Gutenberg : how to get post view count inside Gutenberg Editor (java script file)

Tags: javascript, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a custom block with Gutenberg, I tried but I can not get the post view count in the editor.. there are options (get_post_meta()) in PHP when we run dynamic view .. but I want in editor.js to show admin ...

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useEntityProp()` React hook in your Gutenberg block's `edit` function to get post meta:

```
import { __, sprintf } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useEntityProp } from '@wordpress/core-data';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const Edit = (props) => {
    const postType = useSelect((select) => {
        return select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType();
    });

    const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', postType, 'meta');
    
    return (
        <div>
            { sprintf(__('Number of views: %s', 'text-domain'), meta._my_meta_slug) }
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: ...  really thanks for your reply.. but because i am at a very starting point so .. still i am facing a problem with importing useEntityProps ... :)

./node_modules/@wordpress/core-data/build-module/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (65:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const storeConfig = {
|   reducer,
|   controls: { ...customControls,
|     ...controls
|   },

Comment: * My 
 "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/core-data": "^4.0.1",
    "@wordpress/icons": "^5.0.0",
    "cgb-scripts": "1.23.1",    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }

Comment: The answer assumes you are using [`@wordpress/scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts) with a build process. You could also probably use the `wp` global: `wp.coreData.useEntityProp()`.